# How to get output change according to the dates input by user?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 input tables-
 day_level

```
   Dim_type                       Id                            day_date                    month                 year
    1                              1                            2015-01-05               January                2015
    1                              2                            2015-01-06               January                2015
    1                              3                            2015-01-07               January                2015
    1                              4                            2015-01-08               January                2015        
    1                              5                            2015-01-09               January                2015
    1                              6                            2015-01-10               January                2015
    1                              7                            2015-01-11               January                2015
    1                              8                            2015-01-12               January                2015
    1                              9                            2015-01-13               January                2015
    1                              10                           2015-01-14               January                2015
    1                              11                           2015-01-15               January                2015
    1                              12                           2015-01-16               January                2015
    1                              13                           2015-01-17               January                2015
    1                              14                           2015-01-18               January                2015
    1                              15                           2015-01-19               January                2015
    1                              16                           2015-01-20               January                2015
```

This shows the weekly basis data.
week_level

```
Dim_type                         Id                          week_number                   month                    year
    2                            101                             week1                          January                  2015
    2                            102                             week2                          January                  2015
    2                            103                             week3                          January                  2015
    2                            104                             week4                          January                  2015         
    2                            105                             week1                         February                 2015
```

This shows the monthly basis data.

month_level

```
Dim_type                          Id                                      month                  year
    3                              1001                                  January                 2015
    3                              1002                                  January                 2015
    3                              1003                                  January                 2015
    3                              1004                                  January                 2015         
    3                              1005                                 February                2015
```

I have a 3 tables which have data according to the day level, week level and month level. There is Dim_type column which tells us which data is from which table like

```
dim_type=1 is for day level 

dim_type=2 is for week level

dim_type=3 is for month level
```

Here I am not able to write a function/procedure which on the basis of input dates given by the user can decide which of the data is to be shown-

Here I give you some example suppose the date input by the user `start date- 2015-01-01 and end date- 2015-01-31`. Now here data is needed for whole January month so data will come from month table.
Second like  `start date-2015-01-05 and end date- 2015-01-06`. Now we don't have a complete month on either side so here we have to consider week data. So here output will be like-

```
id                                                                       value                     
102                                                          week2 ( January)  
103                                                          week3 (    ,,       )
104                                                          week4  (    ,,       )
105                                                          week5  (Febuaray)
```

Here whole week is considered because saturday and sunday are non-working day.

Third is like the start date- 2015-01-05 and end date- 2015-01-20 so it will be like

```
 id                                                                   value                     
102                                                          week2 ( January)  
103                                                          week3 (    ,,       )
 14                                                           day level data for 18 January
 15                                                           day level data for 19  January
 12                                                           day level data for 20  January
```

Each table id has unique id which has data and this data is to represented in output according to the date filter. How to writer filter code is that part I need help!

So I am not able make a stored procedure/ functions that will able to tell if there is whole month or this by week data or it should be output as day level. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: I had already made a function for which it gives us aggregation according to the year,quarter or month but I am stuck here how to divide the day :(

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to acheive. You should define the business logics better. What do day, week and month level represent in a date? The second and third examples are confusing

Comment: Actually its not like that...its is just representing the week no of the year..we don't have date at week  or month level that is why I have wrote like this

Comment: I have not added that each table entry has some data and that data should replace value in the example

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you're asking.

There are some caveats: The function will get the number of days in a month based on the start date.
You should store the days in a months table in the database so you're not recreating a temp table again and again.
You'd be better off aggregating the data so you don't need to use this function at all.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ISFullMonth (@StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE)
RETURNS VARCHAR(5)
BEGIN

    /* variables to be used */
    DECLARE @Return VARCHAR(5), @Difference INT, @DaysInMonth TINYINT;

    /* 
        table variable to store the number of days in a month
        this would be better as a fixed SQL table as it'll 
        be called a lot
     */
    DECLARE @Months TABLE 
        ([Month] TINYINT, [NoDays] TINYINT);

    /*
        month values
    */
    INSERT INTO @Months
    VALUES
        (1, 31),
        (2, 28),
        (3, 31),
        (4, 30),
        (5, 31),
        (6, 30),
        (7, 31),
        (8, 31),
        (9, 30),
        (10, 31),
        (11, 30),
        (12, 31);

    /*
        get the number of days in the month
    */
    SELECT @DaysInMonth = [NoDays] FROM @Months WHERE [Month] = MONTH(@StartDate);

    /* 
        Check if it's a leap year and alter the number of days in Febuary to 29 
        This was taken from https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1527/sql-server-function-to-determine-a-leap-year/
    */
    IF((SELECT CASE DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(dd, 1, CAST((CAST(@StartDate AS VARCHAR(4)) + '0228') AS DATE))) 
            WHEN 2 THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
            END) = 1) AND MONTH(@StartDate) = 2
        SET @DaysInMonth = 29;

    /*  
        Get the difference between the two dates
        add 1 to the value to include the first day in the count
    */
    SET @Difference = DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, @EndDate)+1;

    /*
        Check how many days difference there are
    */
    If (@Difference >= @DaysInMonth)
    BEGIN
        SET @Return = 'Month';
    END
    ELSE IF (@Difference > 7)
    BEGIN
        SET @Return = 'Week';
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Return = 'Day';
    END

    RETURN @Return;

END
GO
```

OK This took longer to write than I expected, but here you go.  This should work for now but it doesn't traverse years very well at all.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetDateParts 
(
@StartDate DATE ,
@EndDate DATE
)
AS
BEGIN

    /* variables to be used */
    DECLARE @Return VARCHAR(5)
    /*  
        Get the difference between the two dates
        add 1 to the value to include the first day in the count
    */
    , @TotalNumberOfDays INT
    , @DaysInMonth TINYINT;

    /*  table variable to store the number of days in a month
        this would be better as a fixed SQL table as it'll 
        be called a lot */
    DECLARE @Months TABLE 
        ([Month] TINYINT, [NoDays] TINYINT);

    /* month values */
    INSERT INTO @Months
    VALUES
        (1, 31),
        (2, 28),
        (3, 31),
        (4, 30),
        (5, 31),
        (6, 30),
        (7, 31),
        (8, 31),
        (9, 30),
        (10, 31),
        (11, 30),
        (12, 31);

    /* Create Result table */
    DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE ([MonthNumber] TINYINT, [FullMonth] BIT, [Weeks] TINYINT, [Days] TINYINT)

    -- set the count as the mointh number
    DECLARE @Count TINYINT = MONTH(@StartDate);
    SET @TotalNumberOfDays = DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, @EndDate)+1
    WHILE @Count <= MONTH(@EndDate)
    BEGIN

        /* get the number of days in the month */
        SELECT @DaysInMonth = [NoDays] FROM @Months WHERE [Month] = @Count;

        /* 
        Check if it's a leap year and alter the number of days in Febuary to 29 
        This was taken from https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1527/sql-server-function-to-determine-a-leap-year/
        */
        IF((SELECT CASE DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(dd, 1, CAST((CAST(@StartDate AS VARCHAR(4)) + '0228') AS DATE))) 
                WHEN 2 THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
                END) = 1) AND MONTH(@StartDate) = 2
            SET @DaysInMonth = 29;

        IF (@TotalNumberOfDays >= @DaysInMonth)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @ResultTable ([MonthNumber], [FullMonth])
            VALUES (@Count, 1)

            SET @TotalNumberOfDays = @TotalNumberOfDays - (@DaysInMonth-DAY(@StartDate));

            SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, (@DaysInMonth-DAY(@StartDate)+1), @StartDate);

            SET @Count = @Count + 1;
        END
        ELSE IF (@TotalNumberOfDays >= 7)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @ResultTable ([MonthNumber], [Weeks])
            VALUES (@Count, CAST(@TotalNumberOfDays/7 AS INT))
            DECLARE @Remainder TINYINT = @TotalNumberOfDays%7;

            IF (@Remainder = 0)
            BEGIN
                SET @Count = @Count + 1;
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @TotalNumberOfDays = @Remainder;
            END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @ResultTable ([MonthNumber], [Days])
            VALUES (@Count, @TotalNumberOfDays)
            SET @Count = @Count + 1;
        END

    END;

    -- Return Results
    SELECT * FROM @ResultTable;
END
```

Comment: @Aditya I did think about that and how that could be handled, but the question was phrased in a way that suggested the OP only wanted to know month. But changing it to a stored procedures could easily return a table with quantity of months, weeks and days.

Comment: Yes but I'm on a train at the moment, I can re-write as an sp later.

Comment: ok man...but can you please make it when you reach home as it is kinda important to me...thank you in advance :)

Comment: @AdityaShrivastava How do you change this into a chat? How should the sp handle '2015-05-02' to '2015-06-05' is that one month or 5 weeks?

Comment: you must have 50 reputation to chat...and talking about that date range it should get whole month data for May and 5 days data for June

Comment: @AdityaShrivastava I didn't set nocount to off at the beginning of the script so you are seeing the addition of the 12 months to the temp table then the individual additions to the temp table within the loop.

Comment: sorry but when I checked it again for dates something is missing as like for example I ran it for start date-2015-06-01 to end date 2015-07-01 its showing 1 month and 2 days and also one more issue we cant divide week by 7 we should use calender days like for start date-2015-06-01 to end date 2015-07-11 it should show 1 month 1 week and 4 days week should start from sunday or monday not from day left.